# How to get API response running MVC4 application in cloud?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-storage

I created the web site with database in Windows Azure cloud platform, and 
have published my MVC application into the cloud, but i don't see the api response in XML or JSON formats, i.e. when loading `besmart.azurewebsites.net/api/deals` the only thing i see is:

```
 <Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
</Error>
```

Instead i should see the content of my table in Database.
However when i run the application locally (`localhost:port/api/deals`), i can get JSON file.

Do I need to use connection String of my cloud db? Writing it into Web.config? But when i publish the app, it automatically identifies the connection string.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To give you a better answer, you need to figure out what error you're getting. There are few options, the top two would be logging the thrown exception and checking your logs, or Wrap the GET action method in the Deals controller with a try catch clause and return the exception details in the response by using `return Request.CreateErrorResponse(statusCode, exception)`

Now if I have to speculate (based on your questions), I would say that you're probably not transforming/setting the SQL connection string correctly and it's still pointing to local sql express (default). Have you tried pointing to your cloud db while running your app locally?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `[DataMember]` in your model

You Need to Add `[DataContract]` to your model above the class...

Example:

```
namespace DataContractExample
{
    [DataContract]//<-- Add this to your model
    class exaple
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string example_string;
```